# CakePHP htmlhelper::image adds atribute class depending on the referenced image folder

Tags: html, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I try to display an image with the following code.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('/img/adverts/001/ad.jpg', array('alt' => 'ad')); ?>
```

this creates me this:

```
<img class="zdrwtxgldzisqmpzuclb" src="/img/adverts/001/ad.jpg" alt="werbung">
```

I don't know where this strange class atribute is comming from but it seams to ruin my code as the picture is not displayed.

Now if I use another sub folder in webroot/img, the sub folder uploads like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('/img/uploads/001/ad.jpg', array('alt' => 'ad')); ?>
```

it works and gives back an `<img>` tag without that class.

```
<img src="/img/uploads/001/ad.jpg" alt="werbung">
```

So the question is, where does this class attribute come from, and is this the reason why no image is displayed? I can't find anything about that effect and where it is coming from.

If I add a class attribute to my CakePHP code then it just appends this strange string after my class attribute.

```
 <?php echo $this->Html->image('adverts/01/ad.jpg', array('alt' => 'werbung', 'class' => 'img' )); ?>
 <img src="/img/adverts/01/ad.jpg" alt="werbung" class="img zdrwtxgldzisqmpzuclb">
```

Of course the both folders uploads and adverts have the same rights.

Edit: ndm was right, it is an ad-blocker. Shocking, I didn't know they are that clever.

Comment: Probably some kind of ad-blocker.

Comment: Werbung is German for advertisement - you might want to make it more difficult for adblockers by renaming ad.jpg - ad is short for advertisement in English :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ndm was right. It was the ad blocker "Adblocker Plus" that caused that effect.
The problem is solved.